# php static magic variable set function

Tags: php, static

I have some code I'm working with that was written by the guy before me and I'm trying to look it over and get a feel for the system and how it all works. I am also fairly new to PHP, so I have a few questions for those willing and able to provide.

The basic breakdown of the code in question is this:

```
$__CMS_CONN__ = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
Record::connection($__CMS_CONN__);
```

First question, I know the double underscore makes it magic, but I haven't been able to find anywhere exactly what properties that extends to it, beyond that it behaves like a constant, kind of. So what does that mean?

```
class Record
{
    public static $__CONN__ = false;
    final public static function connection($connection)
    {
        self::$__CONN__ = $connection;
    }
}
```

Second, these two pieces go together. They are each in separate files. From what I've read, static variables can be referenced in the same way as static functions, so couldn't you just call the variable and set it directly instead of using the function?

I get the feeling it's more involved than I am aware, but I need to start somewhere.

Comment: Underscores in identifiers have no special meaning in PHP. But they are usually meant to signalize that the property should be considered internal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a magic variable. The person who wrote that shouldn't really use double underscores for variable names like that because it can cause confusion.

This is just a static property on a class. Which means it is shared between instances of that class (in the same php request).

Have a look at the docs for [static properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) if you're unsure on how these work.

Comment: Ok, so there's no defining your own things as magic, it just applies to the pre-defined php functions with that naming convention. I guess now that I know that I can leave them, be a pain to change them all.

Answer (score 2):

There are several predefined "[magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)" that use this naming style.  However, I don't think the underscores mean anything special (as far as the language is concerned); i.e. defining your own variable like this won't bestow it any magical properties.  It may be part of the previous programmer's naming convention, and if so, it's probably ill-advised.

Setting a property via a function can, in many circumstances, make the "client" code more resilient to changes in the implementation of the class.  All implementation details can be hidden inside the method (known as a "setter").  However, there are strong feelings about whether this is a good idea or not (I, for one, am not a big fan).

Answer (score 1):

1. Two underscores do not make a variable magic.
2. It's better to use getters/setters than to access class properties directly.

Comment: Getters/setters are not best practice. PHP developers were just late discovering that idiom, and even more late in [abandoning it again.](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html)

Comment: While I agree that the implementation should be abstracted, when it's necessary to access properties, it's still not best to access them directly.

Comment: I changed my statement slightly.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP manual has this to say on [naming variables (and other symbols) with underscores](http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.rules.php):

> PHP reserves all symbols starting with __ as magical. It is recommended that you do not create symbols starting with __ in PHP unless you want to use documented magical functionality.

Pay particular attention to the use of the words "reserves" and "documented". They mean double underscores shouldn't be used for user-defined symbols as it may lead to future conflicts, and that unless the symbol is explicitly mentioned in the manual as being magic, it's mundane.